Vmware problems with preallocated disk
Hello i have vmware pro lst version? ahnd do virtual machine With preallocated disk with one file - the size i need 1200 gb. I use m2 disk capability 2 tb (1.81 real place).
Do this - three times.
I create vmware - all good - created disk one disk with Kbuntu 64-bit-flat.vmdk - 1342177280 kb -
after i enable autoprotect shapshow with 5 shapshots - vmware write - that vmware need for this operations 270gb - (after install vmware i have free over 580gb on disk) - i confirm.
And on next day (in the night i start tash to restore big db on vmware for my work) - i have error no enought space on my ssd - and wmware - write all 1.81 tb O_O -and doesnt-t work - vmware create Kbuntu 64-bit-000001.vmdk file with size 560741120 kb which kill all free space......
What a do incortect in the settings - i write all topics many times but...
How many space oh hdd need wmware for normal work? х2? х3? х4 from the occupied place

Which product from VMware are you using exactly? You tagged three very different products, one of them has been discontinued ages ago.

VMware Workstation 17 Pro 17.6.0

My product VMware Workstation 17 Pro 17.6.0
